# Scrapy: scrape succesive urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a very simple question about scrapy. I want to scrape a website with a start_url as www.example.com/1. Then I want to go to www.example.com/2, and www.example.com/3, and so on. I know that this should be very simple, but, how can be done?

This is my scraper, can't be more simple:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/1',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('#Ficha'):
            yield {
                'item_1': quote.css('div.ficha_med > div > h1').extract(),
            }
```

Now, how can I go to http://www.example.com/2?

Comment: a loop should be enough.

Comment: Thank you! I am quite good with php, but a complete noob with Python. I am going to update the question with the actual code, because I can't imagine how to do that in python, and I will need an example…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `start_requests` method to your class and generate those requests as you needed:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "scraper"

    def start_requests(self):
        n = ???                          # set the limit here
        for i in range(1, n):
            yield scrapy.Request('http://www.example.com/{}'.format(i), self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('#Ficha'):
            yield {
                'item_1': quote.css('div.ficha_med > div > h1').extract(),
            }
```

---

Another option is, you can put multiple urls in the `start_urls` parameter:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
                                                 # choose your limit here ^^^

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('#Ficha'):
            yield {
                'item_1': quote.css('div.ficha_med > div > h1').extract(),
            }
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense… :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.http import Request

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"
    number_of_pages = 10 # number of pages you want to parse
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/1',
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.number_of_pages):
            yield Request('http://www.example.com/%d' % i, callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('#Ficha'):
            yield {
                'item_1': quote.css('div.ficha_med > div > h1').extract(),
            }
```